# When to use "was coming" or "would come"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

You went to a party with your friends, you arrived by car and your friend arrived by bus. It was very late at the end of the party and you were driving your friend home.
He said:

> It was really kind of you to drive me home.

You should answer:

> Oh, don't mention it. I **was coming** past your house anyway

or

> Oh, don't mention it. I **would come** past your house anyway

Which one is correct here?
I have googled and read some references, but it's different from my situation

Comment: I think you've reversed *coming* and *going* here.

Comment: Both are possible.  "It was my plan to drive past your house anyway" or "In the normal course of events I would pass your house" - different ways of expressing the same idea.

Comment: *I go this way anyway.*

Comment: If the exchange happened *before* the ride: "I would go past your house anyway". If *after* the ride: "I was coming past your house anyway."

Comment: Can you explain it from a grammatical perspective? Thanks

Comment: There is no grammar issue to explain. You can use different verbs to say you were driving, riding, going, passing, traveling, routing, swinging by, heading.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the perspective of the speaker, the listener, and the direction of travel.

If you were at work and you call your spouse at home, you would say "I'm coming home", because from the perspective of the listener you are travelling towards them.  You might then turn to your colleague and say "I'm going home", because from their perspective you're travelling away.

In that sense, when you think about dropping someone off on your way home, you would use "coming" and "going" based on whether the two of your are travelling to or from a place.

When you're picking someone up, say a colleague on your way to work, then the two of you are travelling towards work together, and it would be normal to say that you were "coming past your house anyway" because the direction of travel for both of your perspectives is **to work**.  If you're dropping them off on the way home, your main shared direction of travel is **from work**, so it would be normal to say you were "going past your house anyway".

The same is true with the party example, but in reality you could use "going" in both cases and it would sound fine.